# Custom icons on TiwulFX DetachableTabPane

Tags: javafx, java-8, icons

We are using TiwulFX for the dockable tabs. Now we are searching how to add custom icons to a DetachableTab. But without any success. Is this even possible to add a icon to the DetachableTab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never used TiwulFX, but looking at the Javadocs, [`DetachableTab`](http://learn.tiwulfx.panemu.com/apidocs/com/panemu/tiwulfx/control/DetachableTab.html) is just a subclass of `Tab`. So you should be able to use exactly the same method to add a graphic as you do with a regular tab:

```
DetachableTab tab = new DetachableTab("Tab");
Image image = new Image("path/to/image.png");
ImageView graphic = new ImageView(image);
tab.setGraphic(graphic);
```